# Get $_POST data from form elements with class attribute rather than id

Tags: php, html, post

Given that the user can use javascript to include an undefined amount of *sorts* how can I get the     $_POST data from all the *select*s on the page since $_POST expects ids rather than classes?

**html file - include_sorts.php**

```
<div class="sorts">
    <select class="departments">
        <option value="1">Finance</option>
        <option value="2">Sales</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**php file - home.php**

```
<?php
     $departments = $_POST['departments'];
?>

<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form action="home.php" method="post">
            <?php
             for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
             {
                 include("include_sorts.php");
             }
            ?>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the for loop added 4 "sorts" to the page, to decorate the question to ensure people understood the scenario. It does do something. There doesn't need to be javascript, because I said "given that the user..." which means assume its there, how it is implemented is irrelevant. It would seem you missed the point completely and then downvoted the question, despite someone else understanding perfectly well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the name attribute is what matters, you can send the selects values as arrays by doing as follows:

```
<div class="sorts">
    <select class="departments" name="sorts[]">
        <option value="1">Finance</option>
        <option value="2">Sales</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="sorts">
    <select class="another" name="sorts[]">
        <option value="1">Foo</option>
        <option value="2">Bar</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah this is a very easy fix, I was expecting something a lot more convoluted. Many thanks!

I assume I can access them using $_POST['sorts'][0]?

Comment: yes, just do var_dump($_POST['sorts']); to check what you get :)